# How to retrieve all user fields with application access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

As per documentation of Facebook of Using App Access Token,

While an App Access Token is largely for the purposes of publishing information back to Facebook on behalf of the user, there is a limited set of information that can be retrieved from Facebook using an App Access Token.

- Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender)
- A User’s Friends and their IDs
- Permissions granted by the User to your App

ref : developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

But I am not able to get mostly fields by application access_token.
I provide all user and friends permissions and extended permissions to a user with ID  UID1

checked as : https://graph.facebook.com/UID1/permissions?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

and I got : ( 1 signifies permission granted and 0 signifies permission not granted.)

```
{

   "data": [
  {
     "installed": 1,
     "read_stream": 1,
     "manage_friendlists": 1,
     "read_mailbox": 1,
     "publish_checkins": 1,
     "status_update": 1,
     "photo_upload": 1,
     "video_upload": 1,
     "create_event": 1,
     "rsvp_event": 1,
     "email": 1,
     "xmpp_login": 1,
     "create_note": 1,
     "share_item": 1,
     "publish_stream": 1,
     "ads_management": 1,
     "read_insights": 1,
     "read_requests": 1,
     "manage_notifications": 1,
     "read_friendlists": 1,
     "publish_actions": 1,
     "user_birthday": 1,
     "user_religion_politics": 1,
     "user_relationships": 1,
     "user_relationship_details": 1,
     "user_location": 1,
     "user_likes": 1,
     "user_activities": 1,
     "user_interests": 1,
     "user_education_history": 1,
     "user_online_presence": 1,
     "user_groups": 1,
     "user_events": 1,
     "user_photos": 1,
     "user_notes": 1,
     "user_questions": 1,
     "user_about_me": 1,
     "user_status": 1,
     "friends_birthday": 1,
     "friends_religion_politics": 1,
     "friends_relationships": 1,
     "friends_relationship_details": 1,
     "friends_location": 1,
     "friends_likes": 1,
     "friends_activities": 1,
     "friends_interests": 1,
     "friends_education_history": 1,
     "friends_online_presence": 1,
     "friends_groups": 1,
     "friends_events": 1,
     "friends_photos": 1,
     "friends_notes": 1,
     "friends_questions": 1,
     "friends_about_me": 1,
     "friends_status": 1
  }
   ]
}
```

Then I make a API call to following URL with APP_ACCESS_TOKEN to retrieve all possible information
https://graph.facebook.com/UID1?fields=id,name,picture,gender,locale,languages,link,username,third_party_id,installed,timezone,updated_time,verified,bio,birthday,cover,currency,education,email,hometown,interested_in,location,political,religion,website,work,relationship_status&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

As a result I got only
    { id, name, gender, locale, username, third_party_id, installed, cover, email and picture }.

Out of which I am able to get

```
{ id, name, gender, locale, username, cover and picture } without any access_token.
```

But Facebook server is not at all sending me all other fields

```
{ location, birthday, relationship_status,languages,link,updated_time,bio,education,hometown,political,religion,work }
```

for which user has authorized the application. Now app_access_token is working fine (I hope so), Thats why I am able to get

```
 { email, installed and third_party_id }
```

but how to get rest fields. Please help me out of the same.